# Meaning of $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x $ and $\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}f(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure

Does
$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x $ and $\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}f(x) $ mean the same thing?

Does $\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}f(x) $ has any meaning unless $f$ is a measure?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $f(x)$ is of bounded variation, $df(x)$ refers to integration with respect to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by $f$.

Comment: In particular, if $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $1$, $\int_0^1 df(x) = f(1) - f(0)$.  The notation is ambiguous if $f$ is not continuous there, because we don't know if we're supposed to integrate over $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$ or $(0,1]$ or $[0,1]$.

Comment: Morally, the integral $\int_{a}^{b}\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)$ may be considered as a limiting version of the Riemann sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \phi(x_i^*) (f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}) $$ for the partition $\{a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = b\}$ and $x_i^* \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$. The notion of Riemann-Stieltjes integral is based on the fact that its limit is well-defined when $\phi$ is continuous and $f$ is of bounded variation, but it may be defined in general situations (with due modification), including the case of Young integral, Lebesuge-Stieltjes integral, stochastic integrals, to name a few.